# Implement Fullcalendar using Struts2

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am doing an appointment application in Java using Struts2 framework. For that am implementing **Fullcalendar** plugin in my application. Am getting error.

**calender.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true,
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'calender',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (doc) {
                            alert(doc);
                            var events = [];
                            events.push({
                                title: doc.title,
                                start: doc.start,
                                end: doc.end
                            });
                            callback(events);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, errorType, error)
                        {
                            alert(xhr.responseText+"::"+errorType + "::" + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
</script>
```

**calender.java**

```
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Action(value = "jsone", results = {
@Result(type = "json", name = "success")})
public class calender extends ActionSupport {
    private String title;
    private String start;
    private String end;

    public String execute() {
        title = "Event";
        start = "2014-10-24";
        end = "2014-10-24";
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="calender"
            class="com.Customer.calender"
            method="execute" >
            <result name="success">/calender.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In jsp am getting **parsererror::SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**
Actually i don't know where the error resides. If anyone implemented fullcalender suggest me any docs asap.

Comment: Don't mess up java/jsp and javascript.

Comment: to display events in calender am going with javascript in jsp page.

Comment: I referred this link and implemented [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001455/full-calendar-struts2-json)

Comment: Is that the whole error message or is there a stack trace?

Comment: **xhr.responseText** returns a error message in that it specifies **SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/project_name] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.xwork.StringUtils**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. I got solution actually am using **struts2.3.4**. I googled and someone says it may be because of dependies(i.e.,libraries/jar) and should use same version struts2.3.4,xwork-core2.3.4 and struts2.json-plugin2.3.4. But previously i used **struts2.json-plugin2.1.8** now i replaced it to **struts2.json-plugin2.3.4** now it is working fine.